# Feature ‘XXX’ for list template ‘YYY’ is not installed in this farm. The operation could not be completed

Tags: list, error, feature, site, exception-handling

So I'm very new to SharePoint. And I'm supposed to debug a website SharePoint 2013. So when I open this page a web service is supposed to get me data from a distant database and display it in a DropdownList. So when the page is displayed nothing happens. I created a label that displays the message of the exception this message says:

> "Feature ‘XXX’ for list template ‘YYY’ is not installed in this farm.
>   The operation could not be completed ".

I thought about displaying the list of all the features using the following commande :

```
Get-SPfeature | Select dispalyname,id
```

but I couldn't find the mentioned GUID among the list.
 I appreciate any suggestion or tip. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you share the code....

Comment: You don't see it under the list means it is not installed in the farm, exactly as error message saying. Probably it was some custom wsp solution that created that list, but now it is uninstalled from the farm. You might need to install it again